# Rows with Award due in 5 years only. Don't want to see Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any more efficient way to see only rows where awards are due?

```
SELECT
    [JobTitle],
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) AS Current_service_years,
    5 + DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) AS Five_years_later,
    CASE
    WHEN 5 + DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) = 20 THEN 'TRUE'
    END AS Award_due
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How about `WHERE [HireDate] IS NOT NULL` at the end?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of  `5 + DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) = 20` you can simply write  `DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) = 15`

And if you only want to setlect rows with award_due=true then shift the condition to where clause as below (it will faster with less rows):

```
SELECT
[JobTitle],
DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) AS Current_service_years,
5 + DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate()) AS Five_years_later,
'TRUE'AS Award_due
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
where DATEDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,Getdate())=15
```

Comment: Perfect thank you works well
But why 15 im abit confused

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur of course making it sargable by using a date window against the raw `HireDate` column would be even better.

Comment: What @DaleK is trying to say, is: don't make the compiler do algebra, it can't do it. It can't solve the equation `WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, HireDate, Getdate()) = 15` so it will just scan the whole table. Instead, help it along with this version `WHERE HireDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -15, GETDATE()) AND HireDate < GETDATE()`

Comment: @Charlieface you crack me up :) your window isn't quite right though, I believe it should only be those which are 15 years old, not from 15-0 years old - so probably more like `WHERE HireDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -15, GETDATE()) AND HireDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -14, GETDATE())` but I didn't have time to ensure that gives the correct window - hence just a comment.

Comment: @Charlieface no - you just seem like a good person to know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add:  `AND so-and-so IS NOT NULL`?

Also – generally speaking you don't have to be concerned about "efficiency."  That's the SQL server's job.  It will use various magical algorithms and statistics to decide, on-the-fly, what is the "most efficient" way to get the right answer.  (See the `EXPLAIN` verb if you're curious ...)

Comment: That's a whopper of a blanket statement: you most certainly **should worry** about efficiency. You often need to help the compiler along a bit, make the query easier for it to understand and optimize. For example, don't put functions on indexed columns in predicates, don't ask for more info than you need, consider your indexing, favour window functions over triangular joins etc etc. Perhaps what you really meant was: there is no need to micro-manage the compiler with things like hints and forced joins, so long as your query is straightforward it should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but ...

Try this:

```
WITH    YearsInService AS
    (
        SELECT
                JobTitle
            ,   Current_service_years   =   DATEDIFF(YEAR, HireDate, GETDATE())
        FROM    HumanResources.Employee
        WHERE   HireDate IS NOT NULL
    )

SELECT
        JobTitle
    ,   Current_service_years
    ,   Five_years_later        =   5 + Current_service_years
FROM    YearsInService
WHERE   5 + Current_service_years = 20
```